# What color were Emmy Noether's eyes?

Tags: mathematics, biographical-details, abstract-algebra

I have [reposted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251570/what-color-were-emmy-noethers-eyes?noredirect=1#comment618682_251570) this question from MathOverflow because it is questionably relevant there.

---

I am looking for a reference that definitively says what the color of Emmy Noether's eyes were. More generally, I would like to find a color photograph of her. Do any exist?

The shading in [this photo](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Emmy-Noether) seems to suggest they are blue, but I am not an expert.

In my search I also found [this document](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~ci3/noetherphoto-engl.pdf) which discusses the difficulty of finding good photographs of Noether.

I have not been able to find this information by (programmatically) searching the texts of existing biographies for the string "eye."

Comment: I am not sure if this is on topic here, unless the color of her eyes is somehow related to her mathematical work. It might fit on History SE http://history.stackexchange.com/questions but I am not sure of that either.

Comment: @Conifold new to this SE, but I would recommend keeping this on topic. Understanding historical figures is a significant part of understanding the history of anything. This question is curiously specific but seems asked in good faith to that end. One might imagine mild applications: reconstructing a picture for a museum, and of course the possibility that aspects of her background we do *not* understand really *are* relevant to her mathematical work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is about a mathematician, it is not about something [related to the person's work](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/q/1/62).

Comment: The only colored image I found is from a [New Scientist feature](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/30/f4/cf/30f4cf237d5133e3a728fda28ecb7f0f.jpg). But it appears to be a colored black-and-white of the one from [Plus Magazine](https://plus.maths.org/content/against-odds) Even if it were genuine it is hard to tell the eye color from it.